# How to parse the string using expression in derived colum in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, expression, etl

In SSIS i am using a derived column to parse the one of the column outputs.
I need to write the expression for this.
For example  some of the outputs are

- https://jbl.abcd.com:66/ABCD//Book_Products/11186-2/Whse/1
- https://jbl.abcd.com:66/ABCD//Book_Products/11184-4/Whse/1
- https://jbl.abcd.com:66/ABCD//Book_Products/11164-2/Whse/2

here my out put should 11186-2 , 11184-5,11164-2 
So basically i need to parse this value which between **Book_Products**/11184-4/**Whse**

I wrote the expression

```
SUBSTRING([@uri],FINDSTRING("Book_Products/",[@uri],1) + LEN("Book_Products/"),FINDSTRING("/Whse",[@uri],1) - FINDSTRING("Book_Products/",[@uri],1) - LEN("Book_Products/"))
```

but its giving

> System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.

Comment: Is @uri a column in a data flow or a variable?

Comment: In situations like this, I find it helpful to identify the tokens - in this case `/`. Add multiple Derived Column expressions in your data flow (or multiple variables if this is actually a Variable) to identify the location of the token. It appears you're looking for the text between the sixth and seventh token so I'd have columns/variables telling me the position of the sixth token. A second one using the location of the sixth, to derive the seventh and then finally, another column which slices that url from sixth to seventh delimiter. If at it breaks, I can debug what piece is wrong

Comment: @uri is a column

Answer (score 1):

The issue was fixed

```
SUBSTRING([@uri],
FINDSTRING([@uri],"Book_Products/",1) + LEN("Book_Products/"),
FINDSTRING([@uri],"/Whse",1) - FINDSTRING([@uri],"Book_Products/",1) - LEN("Book_Products/"))
```

I used expression editor  to debug the expression and it was very useful